# why from $ \int |f_n -f| \to 0$ we can conclude that $ \int f_n \to \int f$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(Ω,A,μ)$ be a measure space and $(f_n)$ a sequence of μ-integrable functions, which converges uniformly to $f:Ω→{\mathbb{R}}$. why from $ \int |f_n -f| \to 0$ we can conclude that $ \int f_n \to \int f$? thanks

Comment: $|\int f|\leq \int |f|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $$|\int f_n-\int f|=|\int (f_n-f)|\le \int |f_n-f|$$ which follows from the linearity of the integral, and the general inequality $$|\int g|\le |\int g|.$$

Comment: if $f$ be non-integrable, Does equality $|\int f_n-\int f|=|\int (f_n-f)|$ is true?

Comment: if $f$ is not integrable, then what does $\int f$ mean?

Comment: if f be non-integrable,$ \int f= \infty$. true?

Comment: not quite. Integrability (in the context of measure theory) means the integral is finite.

Comment: I know it, How can we conclude from inFiniteness of the integral  that there is equality$ |\int f_n−\int f|=|\int(f_n−f)|$?

Comment: the integral is additive.

Comment: oh, thanks Ittay

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left| \int f_n - \int f \right| = \left| \int (f_n - f) \right| \le
\int |f_n-f|
$$